# 000webhosting connecting to mssql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, hosting

I am trying to make PHP retrieve data from a SQL database.

I bought at paid account on 000webhost (which allows for remote SQL access). I then set up a SQL database (included in the package), and tried to access it using PHP.

My code is below:

```
<?php
$myServer = "ip:port";
$myUser = "user";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "dbname";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
    or die("Connection Failed")
?>
```

This throws the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /home/shutdow1/public_html/test.php on line 7
```

Everything I find on google tells me to install modules on the server machine, but I need a **remote** server for this project. What can I do?

Comment: First thing I would advise you to change your password  to MSSQL mediaevally as you published it here on forum

Comment: I recommend highly to delete this question and ask again without the sensitive data

Comment: Thanks for that, changed password. Too tired to think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the mssql module in der `php.ini` its not enabled. If you haven't the module you have to install it first.

https://davejamesmiller.com/blog/php-connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible to install a module on the remote server? It is not hosted on my machine.

Comment: SSH ;) or if its a hoster most times you can configure your server in your Web Interface.